# USBIP on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, usb, ip

I would like use USBIP (USB over IP) on my CentOS 7 server.  I looked at the sourceforge page and I see that USBIP is not incorporated into the kernel.

But I can't find any executable on CentOS related to usbip.  Is there something to install to turn on this feature?

Answer (score 1):

First, add the `elrepo`:

Import the public key and add the repo:

```
rpm --import https://www.elrepo.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-elrepo.org
rpm -ivh http://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.0-3.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm
```

Then, install these packages:

```
yum install kmod-usbip
yum install usbip-utils
```

That will add the feature.

Comment: This seemed to hang when installing kmod-usbip, but did finally complete. So don't give up too quickly. Give it a few minutes.