# CentOS7 - Fatal Module usbip_host not found

Tags: centos

I installed usbip:

```
rpm --import https://www.elrepo.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-elrepo.org
rpm -ivh http://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.0-3.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm
yum install usbip-utils
```

Then I tried to load drivers:

```
modprobe usbip_core
modprobe usbip_host
modprobe: FATAL: Module usbip_host not found.
```

This sound strange. The module seems to do not exist.
I tried to use usbip anyway:

```
usbipd -D
```

Worked.

usbip list -l
 - busid 3-1 (04e6:5116)
   SCM Microsystems, Inc. : SCR331-LC1 / SCR3310 SmartCard Reader (04e6:5116)

- busid 3-14.1 (0557:2419)
  ATEN International Co., Ltd : unknown product (0557:2419)

Worked.

```
usbip --debug bind --busid=3-1
usbip: debug: usbip.c:141:[run_command] running command: `bind'
usbip: debug: sysfs_utils.c:17:[write_sysfs_attribute] error opening attribute /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbip-host/match_busid
usbip: debug: utils.c:47:[modify_match_busid] failed to write match_busid: No such file or directory
usbip: error: unable to bind device on 3-1
```

doen't work.
looking around it seems that usbip_host is missing.
But I cannot load it because seems to be not shipped with usbip package.

I'm stuck

Answer (score 1):

I just realised that the issue was in this answer:

[USBIP on CentOS 7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444858/usbip-on-centos-7)

Which there was a typo in the installation of kmod_usbip:

```
yum install ksmod-usbip
yum install usbip-utils
```

the first line is wrong.
The module is just kmod not ksmod.
The right command is:

```
yum install kmod-usbip
```

I'm gonna to fix original question